# tap on image view to start an activity and implementing pinch zoom on the same image view in android

Tags: android, zooming

Is there any possible way to perform single tap to start another activity on image view and implement pinch zoom on the same image view, I did both independently.

My problem is I don't know if it is possible to integrate them since they both use the event **.ACTION_DOWN**

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Well, you have to implement a listener on imageView and handle these different situations. You have to consider that single tap is one finger, pinching two. So you can easily adopt 2 different listener for managing different actions, and add them to imageView.

Comment: @kinghomer ..thank you,will try it and let u know how it's going :)

Answer (score 1):

You need to use GestureDetectors, they make these distinctions for you:

- The [SimpleOnGestureListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener.html) will notify you for a simple tap through [`onSingleTapConfirmed()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener.html#onSingleTapConfirmed%28android.view.MotionEvent%29).
- The [SimpleOnScaleGestureListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ScaleGestureDetector.SimpleOnScaleGestureListener.html) will handle zoom gestures.

Answer (score 0):

You can use onDoubleTap instead of single Tap:

```
@Override
public boolean onDoubleTap(MotionEvent e)
{
    //open dialog with your image and zoom it
{
```

Comment: This is not really what OP wanted - he wanted single tap